# Question about Dirichlets condition of of a Fourier-Sine series

Tags: continuity, fourier-series

[image]

I dont understand it fully. My graph is in the interval $-2π<t<2π$
And Im asked to find $s(3π)$ which I know is the same as $s(π)$ because the period of a Fourier-sine function is 2π. My graph is the same as the graph in the solutions manual

But what exactly am I looking at here? Since there is discontinuity at s(3π). Dirichlets conditions tell us $s(3π)$ = $\frac {f(3π^+)+(f(3π^-)}{2}$

Where exactly is $f(3π^+) and (f(3π^-)$? Is it the points I have drawn and marked f(3π^+) and f(3π^-) ? The point were the graph is closest to t=3π from both the left hand and right hand side?

The answer says $s(3π)=\frac {f(3π^+)+(f(3π^-)}{2}$ = $\frac {e^0+(-e^0)}{2} = \frac {1+(-1)}{2} = 0$

But I see it as $s(3π)=s(π)=\frac {e^π + (-e^π)}{2}=0$ So I think I am looking at my points wrong.

Comment: You have drawn your function only on one period, you need to $2\pi$-periodize it (the Fourier series is $2\pi$-periodic)

Comment: The original function was $e^t, 0≤ t< π$ and I am asked to draw the graph in the interval $-2π<t<2π$ and calculate $s(3π)$

Comment: No, the original function is periodic, and they only had to define it over one period. That's the point of Fourier series : they apply to periodic functions.